# mySQL Throwing a 1111 Invalid use of Group Function

Tags: mysql

For the life of me I can't figure out why this query is throwing a 1111 error.  Help!

```
SELECT fs.player_id, count(fs.game_id) 
FROM eg.flag_stats fs, eg.flag_games fg
where fs.here = '1'
and fg.start_time > max(re.end_time)
and fs.freq = fg.winning_freq
and fs.game_id = fg.id
group by fs.player_id
order by count(fs.game_id) desc;
```

Please and thanks!

Comment: `max(re.end_time)` -- what are you trying to do here?  What table does `re` alias?  This is where you're having your problem - you can't put the `max` aggregate in the `where` clause.  Sample data and desired results might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sgeddes below is the fix.

```
SELECT pl.name, count(fs.game_id) 
FROM eg.flag_stats fs, eg.flag_games fg, eg.player pl
where fs.here = '1'
and fg.start_time > (select max(end_time) from eg.reset)
and fs.freq = fg.winning_freq
and fs.game_id = fg.id
and fs.player_id = pl.id
group by fs.player_id
order by count(fs.game_id) desc
```